# How to print this pattern using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print this pattern using javascript

```
10
10 20
10 20 30
10 20 30 40
10 20 30 40 50
```

So far I've tried a for loop

```
for (i=10; i<=50; i+=10){
  document.write(i+' \b');
}
```

How should I enhance the code?

Comment: All you need to do is store the last value you printed and prepend that on each iteration.

Comment: Why do you want to "enhance" it? What does that even mean in this context?

Comment: You can "enhance" the code by actually making it work. *Correctness is clearly the prime quality. If a system does not do what it is supposed to do, then everything else about it matters little.--Bertrand Meyer*

Answer (score 2):

```
var i, p = [];
for (i=10; i<=50; i+=10){
  p.push(i);
  document.write(p.join(' ') + '<br>');
}
```

Edit for @macmee

```
var i, p = [];
for (i=1; i<=5; i++){
  p.push(i*10);
  document.write(p.join(' ') + '<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This leaves no trailing spaces at the end of any lines.

```
var p = "";
for (var i = 10; i <= 50; i += 10){
  p += ' ' + i;
  document.write(p.trim() + '<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the issues with using `document.write` for a task like this:

```js
var prevEntry = "";
for (i=10; i<=50; i+=10){
  prevEntry += i+' \b';
  document.write(prevEntry + '<br>');
}
```

Comment: The desired outcome should not have trailing spaces

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a homework question because `document.write` should really never be used, but anyway:

```
// store answer here
var str = '';
// makes sure 1 number is printed on line 1, 2 on line 2, etc
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  // makes sure 1 number is printed on row 1, 2 on row 2, etc
  for(var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    str += (j+1)*10 + ' ';
  }
  str += '<br>';
}
// write it to the document (please consider using jquery instead)
document.write(str);
```